# How to check the type of the parameter sent in a template?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a simple logger which logs different messages to disk. The logger is a simple class of which I've overridden the `<<` operator and, in order to save the messages, I send an enum value signaling to save what has come so far. basically flush everything to the disk.

This is how I intend on using this logger:

```cpp
Logging::Logger << "First " << 255 << "Second" << exc.what() << Logging::Save;
```

As you can see, since I need a way to distinuish between controling arguments such as `Logging::Save` and other normal arguments, I need to know what I'm dealing with.
For getting the type of argument sent, I used `std::is_same`. However, it seems for some reasons the check doesn't work and I get the following error :

```
 In instantiation of 'Logging::Log& Logging::Log::operator<<(const T&) [with T = char [19]]':
104:35:   required from here
47:31: error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'const char [19]' and 'Logging::Mode')
 In instantiation of 'Logging::Log& Logging::Log::operator<<(const T&) [with T = Logging::Mode]':
104:67:   required from here
57:28: error: cannot bind 'std::basic_ostream<char>' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39:0,
                 from 10:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:602:5: note: initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = Logging::Mode]'
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
     ^
```

This is what I have come up so far :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <type_traits>

namespace Logging
{
    enum class Mode
    {
        Save = 0,
        Load = 1
    };
    static constexpr Mode Save = Mode::Save;

    class Log
    {
        private:
            std::stringstream stream;
            bool isNew = true;
            bool displayResults = false;

        public:

            template <typename T>
            Log& operator<<(const T& value)
            {
                if (isNew)
                {
                    stream << "start : ";
                    isNew = false;
                }
        
                if (std::is_same<T, Logging::Mode>::value)
                {
                    if (value == Mode::Save)
                        Save();

                    if (displayResults)
                        std::cout << std::endl;
                        
                    isNew = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    stream << value;
                }
                
                if (displayResults)
                    std::cout << stream.str();
                
                return *this;
            }
            
            void Save(std::string logFilename= "Log.txt")
            {
                isNew = true;

                std::ofstream logFile;
                logFilename = (logFilename == "") ? "Log.txt" : logFilename;
                logFile.open(logFilename, std::ios::out | std::ios::app);

                logFile << this->Get();

                this->stream.clear();
                this->stream.str("");
            }
            
            Log& Display(bool status)
            {
                displayResults = status;
                return *this;
            }
            std::string Get() const
            {
                return this->stream.str();
            }

            friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Log& log);
       };

       std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Log& log)
       {
           os << log.Get();
           return os;
       }
       
       Log Logger;
    }

int main()
{
  Logging::Logger.Display(true)<< "What is your name?" <<Logging::Save;
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you considered an overload of `operator<<` for a `Logging::Mode` argument?

Comment: @Botje No, should'nt the default one be able to handle that knowing  that we are using a template ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it almost correct, `if constexpr(std::is_same<T, Logging::Mode>::value)` is what you want in C++17.

Without `constexpr` the body of the if statement is compiled no matter the condition, this did generate the error about comparing arrays with enums even though the branch is never taken in such case.

`'operator==' (operand types are 'const char [19]' and 'Logging::Mode')`.

Consider using universal references `template<typename T>  T&&` and perfect forwarding for passing `value` around. It is good practice.

In your case a simple overloaded helper method works too:

```cpp
template <typename T>
Log& operator<<(T&& value)
{
    if (isNew)
    {
        stream << "start : ";
        isNew = false;
    }

    helper(std::forward<T>(value));
    
    if (displayResults)
        std::cout << stream.str();
    
    return *this;
}
template<typename T>
void helper(T&& value){
        stream << std::forward<T>(value);
}
// Perfect forwarding requires that the enum is taken by value,
// otherwise the template is a better match in some cases.
//  - Or you would have to write both const& and && versions.
void helper(Logging::Mode value){
        if (value == Mode::Save)
            Save();

        if (displayResults)
            std::cout << std::endl;
            
        isNew = true;
}
```

Comment: `std::forward` instead of `std::move` as you use perfect forwarding. but I would prefer simply `const T&` in that case (no different output/case if passed argument is a const l-value, a non-const lvalue, a rvalue).

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks, fixed it. Well, as I said, I think it is good practice. you do not known which type the user puts in and they are also in the control of `operator<<(std::ostream,T)`. Maybe they can leverage the nature of the value passed to it.

Comment: In that case (`operator <<`), your "good practices" make overloads (and `if constexpr` version too) more complicated (not a big deal with enum or small/trivial types, but for more "complicated" types such as `std::string` or `std::vector`). It is IMO opinion based. Here it is simply more verbose, more complex for no real benefits.